# HTML5 Web Audio Recording and Playing Samples not working with Chrome or Canary

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, audio-recording

All of HTML5 audio recording samples on the internet is not working with Chrome or Canary.

Only "Google search by voice" is working. Why?

Some audio recording sites:
http://www.smartjava.org/examples/webaudio-filters/
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html

Comment: I tried other computer and it is working. Is audio recording not work every computer?

Answer (score 0):

Only chrome canary has the support for audio recording at present. You have to enable the "Enable WebRTC" flag in chrome://flags in the browser. You can check the link that you provided http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html in chrome canary with the flag enabled. The Web Audio APIs will support audio recording across browsers in the future versions. Check this compatibility table.

http://caniuse.com/audio-api    -Compatibility table for Web Audio API

http://caniuse.com/stream -Compatibility table for getUserMedia()

Comment: I tried other computer and it is working with current chrome version but my computer is not recording with 64bit or 32bit OS. I am curious about why my computer is not recording sound with chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Also when i use google's Search by voice feature it is working. Why it is working and audio recording is not working on my computer?

Comment: Did you enable the "Enable WebRTC" flag in chrome?

Comment: I did not enable this flag but how can search by voice working? Also i did not enable this flag on the other computer but audio recording is working.

Comment: Search by voice works in chrome desktop only. It is specific to the webkit. If you are only looking for search by voice feature, you can use <input type="text" x-webkit-speech /> . This will work on chrome only, and I suppose you cannot modify this functionality as of now.